Error de GIT al sincronizar repositorio local con remoto en proyecto ASTRO
cuando instalo proyecto de ASTRO, al intentar sincronizar git aparece ese error y no deja hacer mas nada.
MacBook Air M3, macOS Sonoma




Encontré la solución, se debe al cambio de permisos al directorio .git/. Utilicé la siguiente sentencia y functionó:
sudo chmod -R 775 .git/

